# Diminuindo as conexões com o banco de dados

Tags: php

Bom, sei que cada conexão exige um pouco da memoria do servidor (a quantia exata eu não sei), e sei que varias conexões poderão pesar meu site, pensando nisso eu gostaria de saber se tem como unificar o código:

```
    $proximo = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE ID > ".$pid." AND ID_user = ".$cid." ORDER BY ID DESC")->fetchAll();
if(!$proximo){
print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
} 
foreach ($proximo as $next){};
```

Uso esse código em uma galeria de fotos, onde capturo o ID atual e crio um link que redireciona para a próxima postagem. Seria simples se eu repetisse o código novamente e trocasse o sinal ">" para "<" e consequentemente o nome das variáveis assim eu construiria um link para a postagem anterior. Porém isso exigiria duas conexões simultâneas ao BD, e essas duas conexões mesmo que sejam uteis também se tornam inúteis, já que só servem para criação de dois simples links. Teria como eu usar uma **unica** conexão para criar esses dois links? Ou nesse caso o único jeito é manter ambas as conexões?

Falando sobre esse mesmo código eu gostaria de saber como corrigir um outro "probleminha" que estou tendo com ele, como eu disse, esse código cria um link que avança no ID das postagens, o "probleminha" que surgiu (o que já era esperado), é que ao chegar ao final dos ID que correspondem ao ID_user, surgi um erro dizendo que o ID não existe, e realmente não existe. Teria como então fazer algum comando onde assim que chegar no ultimo ID correspondente ao ID_user o ID 'zere' e retorne ao primeiro ID, criando assim uma especie de loop onde se poderá avançar continuamente?

Comment: Você fará duas queries, mas uma conexão só. $pdo é a conexão, você usará a mesma para os dois 'query'. Outro detalhe, se é só pra link, você nao precisa de foreach, e pode manter o LIMIT1 da outra resposta, pra nao fazer o BD enviar dados desnecessários. Caso vá fazer link pra várias próximas e anteriores de uma vez só, aí a solução dada na outra pergunta poderia ser ajustada para você pegar tudo numa query só, e dividir o resultado em PHP, mas pra isso, teria que ter a certeza de como você quer o resultado.

Comment: Suponhamos então que eu crie 4 códigos parecidos com aquele, mudando apenas as variáveis, porém mantendo o $pdo, o servidor interpretara como apenas uma unica conexão?

Comment: As outras duas foi só pra simular mesmo, pra que eu pudesse ter um intendimento melhor

Comment: Bom, experimentei por um exemplo de como fazer o "loop" na resposta, mas seria legal que você desse mais detalhes ao perguntar, pois se eu ficar só imaginando o que você quer fazer, corro o risco de falar alguma besteira que não serve pro seu caso específico :)

Comment: Opa, te atrapalhando de novo e ainda trabalhando com o mesmo código, gostaria de saber como eu posso 'melhorar' o código. Como eu te disse essa conexão ai tem por objetivo construir o link da próxima postagem e da postagem anterior. Só que é o seguinte, todas as postagens sao cadastradas em uma mesma tabela, e nem sempre essas postagens possuem mídias(imagem ou vídeo), o que causa o seguinte resultado "Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )", seria simples acabar com isso, porem que quero que essas postagens sem as mídias não sejam se quer listadas... (CONTINUA)

Comment: (Continuação), quero que o $next liste apenas os ID's onde o campo "imagem" ou "video" não estiver vazio. Teria como fazer isso que estou te perguntando? Se você preferir abro outra pergunta e coloco todos os códigos assim você poderá entender melhor

Comment: eu acho que seria um exagero uma nova pergunta, bastaria acrescentar os detalhes no WHERE (... AND video = "" AND imagem = ""... e assim vai. Agora, se precisar de nova pergunta, ponha o código atualizado e o mais limpo possível na pergunta nova, pra não confundir o pessoal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar o 1o item ao chegar no último:

```
// Pegamos o próximo
$proximo = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE id > ".$pid." AND id_user = ".$cid." ORDER BY id LIMIT 1")->fetchAll();
if(!$proximo){
   // se nao tem proximo, pegamos o 1o
   $proximo = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE id_user = ".$cid." ORDER BY id LIMIT 1")->fetchAll();
}
```

> Para pegar o **anterior**, usar o `<` na 1a query, e acrescentar o `DESC` **nas duas**.

Tenho a impressão que você está misturando o uso do `>` e do `DESC`, mas só vendo o código real para ter certeza. Acrescentei o `LIMIT 1` supondo que você queira apenas um "próximo" por vez.